# Issue with CI order status

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, rest, woocommerce

This is written in `CI` and using the `wooapi v2`. The order is always being marked as `completed`, instead of `manual renewal`. The goal is that if the post status is already manual renewal, that it will not get marked completed, but stay manual renewal. Any help greatly appreciated. Somewhat new to CI.

```
function complete_order($orderid) { 
    $consumer_key = 'xxx'; // Add your own Consumer Key here
    $consumer_secret = 'xxxx'; // Add your own Consumer Secret here
    $store_url = 'xxx'; // Add the home URL to the store you want to connect to here
    $options = array(
        'debug' => true,
        'return_as_array' => false,
        'validate_url' => false,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'ssl_verify' => false,
    );
    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM xxxxxx WHERE ID = '$orderid'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $poststatus= '. $row["post_status"].';
        if ($poststatus = wc-manual-renewal-re){
            $client = new WC_API_Client($store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);
            $client->orders->update_status($orderid, 'wc-manual-renewal-re');
        }else{$client = new WC_API_Client($store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);
            $client->orders->update_status($orderid, 'wc-completed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the error is in 
$sql ="SELECT * FROM xxxxxx WHERE ID = '$orderid'"; or 
$poststatus= '. $row["post_status"].';

Have tried all I know and cannot fix.

Comment: this doesn't make sense `if ($poststatus = wc-manual-renewal-re){`. First off you are assigning `=` instead of comparing `===` which will always return true, and I guess this should be a string, not a constant:  `wc-manual-renewal-re`

Comment: Thank you. @JImL. A very stupid error on my part. === fixed it. Make it the answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: Changed the title based on the description and formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes/typos in your code here

```
if ($poststatus = wc-manual-renewal-re){
  $client = new WC_API_Client($store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);

  $client->orders->update_status($orderid, 'wc-manual-renewal-re');
}
```

You are assigning `=` instead of comparing `===` which will always return true, and I guess this should be a string, not a constant: `wc-manual-renewal-re`

```
if ($poststatus === 'wc-manual-renewal-re'){
  $client = new WC_API_Client($store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $options);

  $client->orders->update_status($orderid, 'wc-manual-renewal-re');
}
```